# Make localhost phpmyadmin panel available remotely

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm doing a project in java and using my NAS external HDD as a mysql server.

I'm going on vacation and would like to be able to access the phpmyadmin panel remotely so I can verify the java code is performing correctly.

How would this be possible?

I've already setup a dns for the mysql server and configured my external hard drive to automatically update the dns for me.  And my router is port forwarded to the mysql port so that's accessible remotely but what about the phpmyadmin panel? Right now I access it with the usual 192.x.x.x address.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to run your webserver and phpMyAdmin also on the NAS. That way, your MySQL isn't directly exposed to the internet and your MySQL<->phpMyAdmin connection is on the same network segment. Port forward port 443 or 80 for HTTPS or HTTP and access phpMyAdmin directly. Make sure to secure your webserver sufficiently, of course.